# Bash script to check network volume storage

Tags: bash, shell, rsync, du

I am trying to script checking a network volume and comparing it against with a local copy to see if there is enough space to copy the files.

The files will copied using rsync and I use the following to get the available space

```
VAR1=`du -sh /Volumes/networkshare/user`
VAR2=`du -sh /Users/user1/`
```

If I was to do an

```
if [ $VAR1 -lt $VAR2 ]
then echo "Enough Space"
fi
```

Then that might work for the initial backup but this will run once a day using rsync and therefore wont be a good check for available space as only new files and changed files will be copied up. Is there a better way to do this sort of check?

Edit: The share has a size limit of 50gb but I am unsure how I could use this if rsync isnt copying everything

Thanks

Comment: Use the `--dry-run` argument to `rsync` to find out what it will actually transfer and then calculate sizes of those files? (Though this is likely somewhat expensive.)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=$(du -s /Volumes/networkshare/user | cut -f1)
var2=$(du -s /Users/user1/ | cut -f1)

if ((var1 < var2)); then
    ...
fi
```

If you want to sum the needed size for the case 2 (incremental), consider the [Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner)'s proposition bellow your post.

Comment: how is this different from the original?

Comment: Syntactically but it doesn't answer the asked question.

Comment: It's different because -h cause sort command to possibly display size with different **1024 : GB, MB, KB and suchs

Comment: I am using the cut command to do the same thing further down in my script. I have edited original post - there is a 50gb size limit on the share. I know I could hard code the value but if this script is run once daily it will check twice for the same space when the data has already been copied up.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get a feel for the **total size** of the **new or changed files** that will be sent. However, this is before `rsync` computes the **incremental** part of each file that will be transferred if it already exists on the destination host. There is no way to obtain the **incremental size** that `rsync` will actually transfer to update the remote location. This code can be used as a **one-liner** albeit a long **one liner**. Take a look and see if knowing the size of the **new/changed** files helps you in your calculation.

**Note:** the files in the `rsync` command are just for example:

```
rsync -uavn ~/cnf/data nirvana:~/cnf > /tmp/rfn                       # list of files
lns=$(cat /tmp/rfn | wc -l)                                           # line count
xsize=$(tail -n$((lns - 2)) /tmp/rfn | head -n$((lns - 5)) | du -hs)  # isolate files & du
printf "\n You will transfer files totaling : %s\n\n" "${xsize%[^A-Za-z0-9]*}"
rm /tmp/rfn                                                           # remove tmp file
```

**example:**

```
$ bash chksz.sh

 You will transfer files totaling : 8.0M
```

This could be used as an outside approximation of the maximum space the new/changed files would add to the remote storage.

Comment: Thanks for this script. I have implemented it but it doesnt seem to give me an accurate calculation of whats going to be transferred because if I add more files to the directory the size estimated never increases above 292k

Comment: Nathan, remember, what actually gets transferred is only incremental changes to the file. The size of the incremental transfer is not made available by rsync in any form. What I captured by the script is the size reported by `du -hs` (human-readable summary). You can change the `du` option to cause it to show the total bytes instead of `K,M,G,...`

Comment: What is the size reported of duty? The size that is going to be transferred or what exactly is it calculating?

Comment: The size reported by `du` is the **total size of the files that rsync will transfer**. So if there are `10` **new or changed files** `10K` each, `du` will report `100K`. However, if all that is changed in a file is something minimal (like a `newline` added at the end), `rsync` will incrementally transfer (approximately) that one new byte to update the remote file, **not** the entire `10k` of the file. That is what makes `rsync` so efficient. But we mere mortals have no way of knowing (before the xfer) how much of each changed file `rsync` will actually transfer.